# Cold fusion Search Filter / Dreamweaver Plugin

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver

I would like to present a search filter similar to what one might see here (see pic).
I really don't want to spend a long time coding this so is there any plugins or pre built solutions I can integrate to do this?
I am using Coldfusion server and DM front end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look into Solr, it has a feature called "faceting" which allows you to define certain fields in your data, and when a search is fired it returns that list of fields, which all the unique options as well as the count of matches for each option.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/

The learning curve is a little steep at first, but once you get the hang of it, it's exactly what you need for a search filter form like this.